# Set screen resolution for testing full HD on lower resolution monitor

Tags: windows, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, wpf

I have a WPF app, and I know it has problems on full HD screens, but my display is 1440x900. How can I simulate full HD on my monitor? My graphic driver shows max resolution is 1440x900.

I guess scrolling feature found on some ATI drivers would be good, but by driver doesn't support it.

(I am using a dual output NVidia on Windows 8)

Comment: I am using a dual output NVidia on Windows 8 @Psycogeek

Comment: Ow, thanks found "Customize" button in NVidia panel! Write it as answer to I accept it for you :) @Psycogeek

Comment: If you know all the steps to do it, so you can help someone else do the same thing, then please self answer your question with all the details. Then I will remove the comments.

Answer (score 2):

With help of @Psycogeek I found how to customize resolution in NVidia driver, check screenshot below :

I just added 1920x1080, 60hz, my monitor warned non-standard resolution, but worked properly. Now I can check my app in real full HD. Unlink old days, it's not scrolling, just scaled screen to fit my device ( some pixel aliases appear)

[image: Check this image]